# "P-U-L-L" vs. "P-U-double L"

Tags: pronunciation, dialects, spelling-pronunciations

I have heard some people spell double letters individually, e.g. "B-B", "C-C", or "D-D". But I have also heard others use the word *double* instead. Is there any dialectical preference? Is there any such thing as American vs. British in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is absolutely standard in British English to use "double" for repeated letters when spelling words, and sounds odd not to do so. It is also common for repeated digits when reciting numbers digit by digit.

My observation is that the usage is much less common in American English, and may indeed be misheard as "W".

Comment: The only notable exception that comes to mind is in the case of "w-w-w" where we pronounce the three w's individually rather than saying "triple w"

Comment: Presumably the spelling "h-e-double-hockey-sticks" for _hell_ is of North American origin, given our relative enthusiasm for the game.

Comment: I'd say this usage is moderately common in the U.S. as well; you probably shouldn't be misheard if you use it. But it's not so common that it sounds odd not to use it.

Comment: @MarkFarnell: I don't think "triple" (or "treble") is nearly as common - it almost never comes up in spelling, of course. I have long referred to that as "treble-u", which is inaccurate but cute.